# how to intersect elements of one column along with group_by in R

Tags: r, dplyr, set-intersection, set-operations

Lets assume, my data is like

```
  group_id    col1
1        1     A,B
2        1     B,C
3        2     A,C
4        2     B,D
5        3     A,D
6        3 A,B,C,D
```

I would like to summarise/mutate col1 where its elements are intersected within same group (over group_id). My required output is like (if summarising)

```
  group_id col1
1        1    B
2        2 <NA>
3        3  A,D
```

or like this (if mutating)

```
  group_id col1
1        1    B
2        1    B
3        2 <NA>
4        2 <NA>
5        3  A,D
6        3  A,D
```

I can easily create a union by using function `toString` but scratching my head for how to have common elements in the output.  Basically `intersect` requires at least two arguments and is therefore not working here.

dput(df) is as under

```
df <-  structure(list(group_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), col1 = c("A,B", 
"B,C", "A,C", "B,D", "A,D", "A,B,C,D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split `col1` on comma and use `Reduce` + `intersect` to get common values in each `group_id`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  summarise(col1 = toString(Reduce(intersect, strsplit(col1, ','))))

#  group_id col1  
#*    <int> <chr> 
#1        1 "B"   
#2        2 ""    
#3        3 "A, D"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ronak.  It is working as expected.  Let me check other answers before accepting one.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate_rows(col1) %>% 
   group_by(group_id, col1) %>% filter(n()>1) %>% 
   distinct() %>% group_by(group_id) %>% summarise(col1 = toString(col1)) %>% 
   right_join(df %>% select(group_id) %>% distinct()) %>% 
   arrange(group_id)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
Joining, by = "group_id"
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group_id col1 
     <int> <chr>
1        1 B    
2        2 NA   
3        3 A, D
```

Answer (score 1):

One option using `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 separate_rows(col1) %>%
 count(group_id, col1) %>%
 group_by(group_id) %>%
 summarise(col1 = if_else(all(n == 1), NA_character_, paste(col1[n == 2], collapse = ",")))

  group_id col1 
     <int> <chr>
1        1 B    
2        2 <NA> 
3        3 A,D
```